# Not allowing me to set a listener to any of the ports (Oracle Netca)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

Every single time i attempt to assign a port to a new listener that i am trying to create, the Net Configuration Assistant (Netca) throws me up the issue that the port is currently in use. I have tried this 10's of times for a vast range of ports. I've even found out via the command prompt which ports aren't in use and attempted them, however it just seems impossible to get the NetCa to assign this listener to any port. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

[before error with random port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx4ev.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntGQu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely cause of the error is duplicate IP addresses or duplicate hostnames in /etc/hosts file, or the hostname isn't qualified.

Comment: Any advice on how i should go about making progress with solving this issue?

Comment: If "this issue" is getting Network Configuration Assistant to not show that error, then correct the `/etc/hosts` file. If "this issue" is just configuring a listener, we can go old school and ditch the Network Configuration Assistant and just edit the `$TNS_ADMIN\listener.ora` file. Why are we creating new listeners? What problem are we solving by creating new listeners? How many listeners do we actually need?

Comment: Ah sorry about being vague, this is my first question on stack overflow after all. Right so i am configuring this new listener in order to interact with an oracle database in a windows form in visual studio. I'm using mySQL to interact with the database and add data. There is a huge possibility i'm going about this in the wrong way as databases are very new to me? I believe i require a configured listener to interact with it in mySQL? However i really am not too sure. Either way, it would be good to know that i can successfully configure a listener for future reference. @spencer7593

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue came from the Docker for Desktop automatic configuration that indeed changed the `/etc/hosts` file as Spencer said but it was not a duplicate IP address. I already had Docker for desktop uninstalled so I did not need the configuration anyway.

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
#192.168.1.13 host.docker.internal
#192.168.1.13 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
#127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

As soon as I disabled the Docker for Desktop automatic configuration the netca worked as expected.